# jQuery $.each() fumbles if non-Array object has length property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I'm working on a [very, very, very simple library](https://code.google.com/p/shadejs/) to provide some convenience functions for working with native JavaScript objects, ideally (eventually) in a jQuery-like manner.

I have a dead-simple function: `crawlObject` which I modified to use jQuery's `each()` instead of a `for(var key in obj)` loop.

```
function crawlObject(thisObj, onSuccess, doRecursion) {
    var stopCrawling = false;
    if (isFunction(onSuccess) && ($.isPlainObject(thisObj) || isArray(thisObj))) {
        $.each(thisObj, function(childKey, value) {
            var childObj = thisObj[childKey];
            if (false === stopCrawling) {
                stopCrawling = isTrue(onSuccess(childObj, childKey, thisObj, value));
            }
            if (false === stopCrawling && doRecursion) {
                stopCrawling = isTrue(crawlObject(childObj, onSuccess, doRecursion));
            }
        });
    }
    return stopCrawling;
}
```

This has the advantage of crawling both Array objects and "plain" JS objects without additional logic.

But.

If I pass a "plain" JS object which happens to have a property name of 'length', each() implodes like a dysfunctional phoenix. This might happen if I am recursing on a large object defining DOM elements, which might include a length property intended to indicate a character display length in the UI. A value of 200 here is disastrous: suddenly each() is iterating 0-199 on the value of the prop.

Before I invest in any further refactoring, has anyone stumbled on a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's [documentation for jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) clearly states that if the object has a `.length` property, then it iterates by numeric index from 0 to length-1 (like you would expect for an array or array-like object).

If you have an object with a `.length` property and the things you want to iterate are not numeric indexes from 0 to length-1, then `jQuery.each()` will not do what you want and you should not be using it.

Here's the specific code for `jQuery.each()` from the jQuery source.  You can see on the 2nd and 3rd lines of the function that if there's an `object.length`, `isObj` will be `false` and it's not going to treat is as an object later:

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length,
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ i++ ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
},
```

Comment: I'd beg to differ that the documentation is "clear": 'Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object)' doesn't quite convey the full extent of the import of this design choice (on jQuery's part). This (to me) indicates some sort of prototype check in addition to a hasOwnProperty('length'). But, you're right. There it is. Still, I'm dealing with complex, arbitrary objects. Only a small fraction might have a 'length' property--I'm not averse to adding more conditional logic to handle the edge case, I'm just wondering if there's another way.

Comment: You can always look at the jQuery code for `jQuery.each()`.  The relevant line is this: `length = object.length, isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );`.  You can clearly see that it's going to treat it as an object only if there's no `.length`.

Comment: there it is. Well, it is what it is. That answers the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think if(thisObj.hasOwnProperty("length")) might do it for you

Comment: Traditionally, yes--that's the proper way to iterate loops. But in this case, it's jQuery's each that is the problem: in `$.each({ name: 'My Thrifty Prop', length: 200}, function(key, value) { alert(key); } );`, you'll get a series of alerts 0-199. Evaluating for $.isArray() and hasOwnProperty('length') is means of bypassing $.each(), but I don't think it solves the problem. Of course, this may not be solvable using $.each()--I'm just curious if there's a way to make it work.